# Two questions regarding Big-O,Theta and Omega notation

Tags: big-o

Prove or disprove the following claims:

1. Exist function `f(n)` so `f(n-k)` is not equal to `Big-theta (f(n))`. when `k>=1` and is positive constant.

Is there any function which this claim is true?
I thought about `f(n)=n!` but I'm not sure that's is correct answer.
Moreover, if `f(n)=n!` is correct, how this claim can be proved?

2. Exist function so `(f(n))^2=Big-O(f(n))` and `f(n)=Big-omega (log(log(n)))`.

I think there is not function which make the claim to be true. 
If this is correct - how it could be proved?

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct for f(n) = n!. It suffices to show that for any fixed k >= 1, (n - k)! is not Omega(n!), as for any constant c > 0, it holds for all n large enough that c * n! > (n - k)!.
2. There is no f(n) such that both f(n)^2 = O(f(n)) and f(n) = Omega(log log n). The latter implies that for some constant c > 0 and all n large enough, f(n) > c log log n, and in particular f(n) > 1 for all n large enough. If we now assume that f(n)^2 = O(f(n)), then there exists a constant r > 0 so that for all n large enough, f(n)^2 < r * f(n), namely f(n) < r. But this implies that log log n < (r / c) for all n large enough, which is false for all n > e^(e^(r / c)) (where e is the basis of log).

Comment: Regarding question one, do you have one more example of function which makes the claim to be true?